# Difference of "ab-/ausschalten" in technical context

Tags: meaning-in-context

The meaning in common German seems synonymous, but is there a difference in specific technical/industrial/scientific fields?

Personally i would say

> den TV ausschalten

but refer to *Abschaltung* when using the noun in a technical context. Pure habit probably...

Comment: +1 _Abstellen_ would be another option, but it's probably not being used that much in a technical context ...

Comment: There is also a different (more final) meaning to "abschalten" when it comes to demonstrations agains nuclear power: "Krümmel abschalten"

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Both, *"ausschalten"*, and *"abschalten"* are synonyms in general as well as in technical usage.

In colloquial German however nobody would say *"ich schalte den TV aus"*. Nearly all people I know put it like this:

> *"ich mache den Fernseher aus"*

or, to their kids

> *"macht bitte den Fernseher aus"*.

It may be that from this colloquial usage *"ausschalten"* is more often used than *"abschalten"*.

As the nouns *"das Ausschalten"* or *"das Abschalten"* should be sufficient for describing the act of switching off, more complicates versions like *"Ausschaltung"* or *"Abschaltung"* were created without adding more information. The term *"Abschaltung"* is preferably used in context of nuclear plants.

When using *"Ausschaltung"* there may be confusion from it's other (euphemistic) usage in the meaning of eliminating opponents (best seen in the frequent usage during war times in a [Google Ngram](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=ausschalten,%20abschalten&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=8&smoothing=3))

Comment: I say "Ich schalte den Fernseher aus." also in colloquial form (but I'm not from Germany.)

Comment: Good to hear. I say "ich lösche das Licht" ;)

Comment: a) Ich sage "ich schalte den Fernseher aus" und bin Eingeborener. b) Ich kenne Leute, die sagen "Schalt mal den Herd leise", und meinen damit, von Stufe 3 auf 0.5 zurückschalten. Kranke gibt's!

Comment: Ähnlich wie das Ausschalten eines Gegners (auch beim Sport) wird aber für Schläfer der Begriff `abschalten` verwendet.

Comment: @user Enttarnt, nur ein Ex-BND Agent kann das Insider-Wissen haben. Jetzt macht auch dein Benutzername Sinn ;) Wobei bei 007 doch immer von *ausschalten, kaltstellen, auf Eis legen, es wie einen Unfall aussehen lassen* geredet wird :) Oder ich schau zu wenig Tatort...

Comment: @Takkat *Es werde dunkel* Einfach mal ausprobieren! ;)

Answer (score 7):

First,it should be:

> Den Fernseher ausschalten
>   Das TV abschalten

Second, **ausschalten** is just separating from power (in case of an electrical device).
While **abschalten** is more subtle. It's like going offline, if I might say so.

Indeed, even humans can **abschalten** themselves:

> Entschuldige, ich hatte gerade abgeschaltet, was sagtest du?

Thus, "abschalten" may(!) mean to turn some functions of a complex system partly off, while "ausschalten" means the system is completely off. For example, a SAT-TV receiver can record a movie or football game, even when it is abgeschaltet, but not if it is ausgeschaltet.

Comment: Außerdem sind die Geräte, die scheinbar ab- oder ausgeschaltet sind, aber wie von Geisterhand dann doch aktiv werden, in den Bereitschaftsmodus versetzt worden. Dass eines von beiden ab, aber nicht ausgeschaltet heißt, oder umgekehrt, müßte wenn, dann eine lokale Besonderheit sein. Ich tippe eher auf Einbildung.

Comment: Ähnlich "Netzabschaltungen" - hier werden bestimmte Netzsegmente abgeschaltet, aber das Netz als solches arbeitet weiter.

Comment: I would propose this small difference in meaning, where "abschalten" means "turn off" for a shorter period of time as "ausschalten". For example, one might "ausschalt" the central heating of a building during the winter, but "abschalt" it for maintenance.

This  fits with the term "Netzabschaltung": The power is meant to come back as soon as possible.

Comment: Wer 'das TV' sagt, müßte auch 'das CDU' sagen.

Comment: Wenn man überhaupt TV in seinem Wortschatz hat, dann sollte man in Verbindung mit ausschalten daran denken, daß es TelevisionsGERÄT heißen könnte. Oder wie schaltest du eine Vision aus?