# Is there a difference between "anschalten" and "einschalten"

Tags: meaning, word-choice, word-usage, difference

Is there a difference between *anschalten* and *einschalten*?

If I turn on the TV, oven, heat, start the car etc., can either verb be used?

Comment: related: http://german.stackexchange.com/questions/2480/difference-of-ab-ausschalten-in-technical-context

Comment: Note that there's a similar pair for the opposite: _abschalten_ and _ausschalten_

Comment: To start a car: ein Auto anlassen
(neither `anschalten` nor `einschalten` nor `einlassen`)

Comment: To *start* [the car, a motor] you use *anspringen*

Comment: Not exactly, there is a difference between who is acting. Ich starte den Motor, das Auto springt an.

Comment: Another word with the same meaning is »aufdrehen«. It comes from that times when rotary switch was the standard switches to turn on the light. It is still used for example if you turn on the TV by pressing a button on a remote control: »Den Fernseher aufdrehen«. Turn off is »abdrehen«.

Answer (score 22):

Generally both words *einschalten* and *anschalten* mean the same thing. Duden defines them as

> durch Betätigen eines Schalters in Betrieb setzen

Thus you can *ein-* and *anschalten* the following things:

- Licht
- Fernseher, Radio, Computer
- Mikrowelle, Ofen
- Heizung
- ...

While I would use *einschalten* rather than *anschalten* in most cases, Google shows a lot of hits for *anschalten* though. I assume a regional difference in respect to frequency. Others may elaborate on this thought.

In case of heating, however, I'd use *einschalten* and *anschalten* when activating the heating system in autumn (i.e. it was completely shut down during summer); and *anmachen* (colloquial version of *einschalten* and *anschalten*, respectively), *aufdrehen* or *hochdrehen* (*drehen* defines the sort of action/movement you do when you turn on a radiator) when it's cold and I want the radiator to work.

In the end, it's similar to *turn on/off* and *switch on/off* in English. You can interchange them quite often as well.

Comment: +1 especially for mentioning anmachen, which I would use for any to turn on I can think of. ... and then of course there is also anstellen. I'd say ___schalten is not used that much, at least not in the Berlin area.

Comment: I only ever heard _machen in Hessen, mostly from teenagers. I did hear _schlaten a few times though. _machen was even more frequent in cases like reinmachen or hinmachen as well. Seemed a little lazy xD

Comment: You can additionally, use *einschalten* in the sense of getting someone involved: *die Polizei/Behörden/Eltern einschalten*.

Answer (score 6):

The meaning is the same. 
Einschalten is used way more commonly in written and spoken German.
Anschalten is used less, only in spoken German and is the less formal word.

Answer (score 3):

The [ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=eingeschaltet,angeschaltet,einschalten,anschalten&year_start=1900&year_end=2008&corpus=20&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1;,eingeschaltet;,c0;.t1;,angeschaltet;,c0;.t1;,einschalten;,c0;.t1;,anschalten;,c0) on the following four forms shows a superior usage of `einschalten` and a slight augmentation concerning `anschalten` since the turn of the millenium

> **eingeschaltet** - blue
>   **angeschaltet** - red
>   **einschalten** - green
>   **anschalten** - orange

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Although both terms usually mean to turn things on, "Einschalten" can also be used for persons or departments when they are brought into something. Like:

> Er hat einen Rechtsanwalt eingeschaltet.
>
> Die Polizei hat sich eingeschaltet.
>
> Das Amt für Migration schaltet sich ein.

You could not use anschalten for this purpose.

If you want to turn *someone* on, you couldn't use neither einschalten nor anschalten, but *anmachen*.

Answer (score 0):

While I also consider *anschalten* and *einschalten* as mostly synonymous (no difference in your examples), I'd like to add the following

*Anschalten* has a (rarely used) additional meaning, which I would consider as technical term and which relates to the equally rarely used substantive *Anschaltung*:

This means, to

> add some device to an already existing wiring

and has a very similar meaning to *anschließen* (connect).

Examples (unfortunately for *Anschaltung* only, since internet search for *anschalten* apparently yields only false positives):

- Anschaltung zusätzlicher Endgeräte
- DSL-Anschaltung