# Unterschied zwischen "anmachen" und "einschalten"

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, verb

Ich habe einen Beispiel, um die Unterschied zwischen die zwei Verben zu verstehen.

Wenn das Licht ist aus, und du magst das nicht, fragst du:

> Kannst du bitte das Licht *anmachen*?

oder

> Kannst du bitte das Licht *einschalten*?

Sind die zwei Sätze gleichwertig? Was ist die Unterschied, wenn es gibt eine?

Comment: [Is there a difference between “anschalten” and “einschalten”](http://german.stackexchange.com/q/5977/1224) - *Anmachen*: colloquial

Comment: Hearing "einschalten" in context of light would strike me as extremely odd and unidiomatic. Might be a regional thing but I think it is save to say that "anmachen" is the better choice in all situations

Comment: @Emanuel Thanks. I need to clarify that I made the examples up, I have no idea whether it's a regionalism or not. I just needed something to write a sentence.

Comment: _Einschalten_ sounds perfectly fine to my (Austrian) native ears.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Einschalten setzt im Prinzip einen Schalter voraus. Ich könnte auch Licht anmachen, indem ich eine Kerze anzünde. Eine Kerze kann ich aber nicht einschalten.

Ansonsten hat das Wort anmachen auch weitere Bedeutungen. In diesem Zusammenhang (Licht) ist es jedoch eindeutig. Und wie schon erwähnt ist anmachen eher umgangssprachlich.